# Symfony htaccess to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, subdirectory

I have some domain e.g domain.com
In main folder I have a phpBB forum.
I have my Somfony 3.4 app in subfolder named e.g. symfonyfolder.
I have problem with my .htaccess file.
In main folder I have normal phpBB .htaccess and I added:

```
RewriteRule symfonyfolder/(.*) symfonyfolder/web/$1 [L]
```

In symfonyfolder I do not have .htaccess file. In symfonyfolder/web I have such .htaccess file:

```
    DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]


    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

But then I get uri like that:

```
domain.com/symfonyfolder/web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//web//
```

What have I done wrong?

//Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4

Comment: RewriteRule symfonyfolder/(.*) symfonyfolder/web/$1 [L]
This will add "/web/" to every request. so you need a condition before that statement where you exclude /web

Comment: Ok, I add that condition. But now symfony creates routes like domain.com/xxx without 'symfonyfolder', do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: please update your question. i dont know what you mean with "that condition"

Comment: "you need a condition before that statement where you exclude /web"
But I found how to add prefix in router and thanks for your help